# selected option in ng-options in agularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to have a selected option in the dynamic select box.

select box not showing any value as selected

```js
$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $rootScope.API_URL + 'branchesShow/' + $routeParams.id,
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
               
                $scope.city_id = response.data.data.city_id;
             
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
               // console.log(response);
            });


            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $rootScope.API_URL  + 'citySelectList',
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              
                $scope.cities = response.data.data;
               
                console.log($scope.cities);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

```html
  <select class = "form-control"  ng-model="city_id" ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in cities">
</select>
```

Comment: Could we see the output of those console.log's, its very hard to debug when we can't see what data you are working with. Maybe try to mockup a simple plunker?

Answer (score 0):

I think your $scope.city_id doesn't contain an appropriate id value, as i can see you have ng-model directive and an option should be selected if the value in city_id matches an id of an object in your list.

Check if there is something wrong in the data, here is a little snippet to help you :

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.cities = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'City 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'City 2'
    },
  
  ]
  
  $scope.city_id = 1;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">


  <select class = "form-control"  ng-model="city_id" ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in cities">
  </select>

</div>
```